# MultiIndex DataFrame with all Nan values

Tags: python, multi-index

I had a DF whuch I made a MultiIndex one. The main one was full with float values, but hen I transformed it, it became all Nan.

This is the initial one:

[image]

And this is after the MultiIndex:

[image]

This is the code I used:

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
            ('Age', '0-18'),('Age', '19-45'),('Age', '46-65'),('Age', '65+'),
            ('Gender', 'Male'),('Gender', 'Female')])

df_final = pd.DataFrame(df_output, columns=cols, index = df_output['SHELL_COUNTRY'])
```

And then exported it to excel file like this:

```
df_final.to_excel(xl_output_2, index = True, index_label=None)
```

How should I fill it in with the values from the initial one?

Comment: could you show the contents of the whole dataframe `df_output`?

It's possible there's no data in the Shell_country column...